# Accessibility Issue in selected Devices

Tags: angularjs, html, accessibility, samsung-mobile

The following snippet unable to deduct by the samsung edge device accessibility.

Can you suggest me what went wrong as well as what is the best way to test across multiple device variants.

```
     <div class="text-center ng-binding" role="main" tabindex="0" 
         ng-bind-html="variable | parseHtml"><p>text: Sample text </p>
     </div>
```

Raja K

Comment: You have a space between `ng-bind-` and `html`. Typo?

Comment: yes. sorry. updated